# Mpeg-dash support in nginx-plus

Tags: nginx, rtmp, mpeg-dash

I searched enough but couldn't sort out how to configure mpeg-dash in nginx plus .

rtmp module is supporting it i guess but i dont understand it much how can i configure it and request it in nginx plus server.

When i configured rtmp in nginx.conf getting the error

```
 unknown directive "rtmp" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:13
```

Configuration is

```
  user  nginx;
  worker_processes  auto;

  error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
  pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


  events {
      worker_connections  1024;
    }

   rtmp {         
     server {

    listen       98;
    server_name  127.0.0.1;          

    application dash {
         live on;
         dash on;
         dash_path /usr/share/nginx/html/dash;
    }
  }
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;

server {
    listen       99;
    server_name  127.0.0.1;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /crossdomain.xml;
}

location = /crossdomain.xml {
    root /var/www/crossdomain;
}


    location /images {
        root   /usr;
    }

    location /flv {
        root   /usr;
        flv;
        mp4_buffer_size       1m;
        mp4_max_buffer_size   5m;
        mp4_limit_rate        on;
        mp4_limit_rate_after  30s;
    }

    location /video {
        root   /usr;
        mp4;
        mp4_buffer_size       1m;
        mp4_max_buffer_size   5m;
        mp4_limit_rate        on;
        mp4_limit_rate_after  30s;
    }

    location /hls {
         root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
         hls;
         hls_fragment            5s;
         hls_buffers             10 10m;
         hls_mp4_buffer_size     1m;
         hls_mp4_max_buffer_size 5m;
         types 
        {
               application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
               video/mp2t ts;
        }

  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
  add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache';
    }

    location /dash {
         root /usr/share/nginx/html;
         add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
     }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

}

How can i enable rtmp in nginx-plus

Answer (score 0):

The `rtmp` section must be placed outside the `http`, like this:

```
rtmp {
    server {
    ...
}

http {
    server {
    ...
}
```

For a full example see the Readme: https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module

Comment: That is there already but i have installed nginx-plus and not able to add ngnx rmtp module to it  so its showing rmtp is unknown directive

Comment: For whatever module i am putting getting the error as "Unknown directive" For ex : image_filter rotate 90 i tried . My question is how can we configure some other module in nginx-plus

Comment: @RachitGupta Nginx Plus already includes the RTMP module as far as I know. You are missing the `http` directive in the configuration posted in your question. Is this a typo, or where is it exactly?

Comment: http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
 server {
        listen       99;
        server_name  127.0.0.1;
  location /video {
            root   /usr;
   mp4;
        }
  
  location /dash {
             root /usr/share/nginx/html;
             add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
         }
    }
   include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
Its there already.I tried to yum install nginx-plus-extras as i read somewhere it has rmtp support but getting the error "Processing conflict nginx plus conflicts nginx-extras"

Comment: Not only rmtp but many modules like image-filter is also not working.I believe its not present in nginx-plus .Could you please help?

Comment: I am using trial version of nginx-plus. Is that why its not available

Comment: Ok I have placed the complete nginx-config info in original question